# What to do if Android emulator has flickering rendering issues?

Tags: android, android-emulator

when I'm trying to start the emulator on my computer (Ubuntu / amd64), the Android emulator looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpM95.jpg

For me it heavily looks like a GLES / OpenGL emulation issue, but I have no idea where to start debugging. Other OpenGL-using applications, such as games in Steam, work perfectly without issues.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be evicted by enabling virtualization in your PC (Virtualization should be enabled in your BIOS settings). But your processor should support virtualization. Assuming that you have virtualization facilities, follow the following steps so that you can boost up performance of your android emulator.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213272